# How to search special characters(+ ! \ ? : ) in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I want to search special characters in index.

I escaped all the special characters in query string but when i perform query as + on lucene in index it create query as +().

Hence it search on no fields.

How to solve this problem? My index contains these special characters.

Comment: PLease give an example of what you are searching and what is created. What do you mean with "query as +"?

Comment: I am searching for special characters like + ! ? etc. Well I got the solution. Actually we are using some custom analyzer and because of filters applied it was giving blanck query( +() ). But when i used KeywordAnalyzer it worked. **Any how any input on it?**

Comment: Are you using the same analyzer for indexing and for the query? Please add a code example describing your exact query and how you process it before calling the search.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using the `StandardAnalyzer`, that will discard non-alphanum characters. Try indexing the same value with a `WhitespaceAnalyzer` and see if that preserves the characters you need. It might also keep stuff you don't want: that's when you might consider writing your own Analyzer, which basically means creating a TokenStream stack that does exactly the kind of processing you need.

For example, the `SimpleAnalyzer` implements the following pipeline:

```
@Override
public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
   return new LowerCaseTokenizer(reader);
}
```

which just lower-cases the tokens.

The `StandardAnalyzer` does much more:

```
/** Constructs a {@link StandardTokenizer} filtered by a {@link
StandardFilter}, a {@link LowerCaseFilter} and a {@link StopFilter}. */
@Override
public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    StandardTokenizer tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer(matchVersion, reader);
    tokenStream.setMaxTokenLength(maxTokenLength);
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(tokenStream);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    result = new StopFilter(enableStopPositionIncrements, result, stopSet);
    return result;
 }
```

You can mix & match from these and other components in `org.apache.lucene.analysis`, or you can write your own specialized `TokenStream` instances that are wrapped into a processing pipeline by your custom `Analyzer`.

One other thing to look at is what sort of `CharTokenizer` you're using. `CharTokenizer` is an abstract class that specifies the machinery for tokenizing text strings. It's used by some simpler Analyzers (but not by the `StandardAnalyzer`). Lucene comes with two subclasses: a `LetterTokenizer` and a `WhitespaceTokenizer`. You can create your own that keeps the characters you need and breaks on those you don't by implementing the `boolean isTokenChar(char c)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not actual for the author but to be able to search special characters you need:

1. Create custom analyzer
2. Use it for indexing and searching

Example how it works for me:

```java
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.custom.CustomAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.*;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class LuceneSpecialCharactersSearchTest {

/**
 * Test that tries to search a string by some substring with each special character separately.
 */
@Test
public void testSpecialCharacterSearch() throws Exception {
    // GIVEN
    LuceneSpecialCharactersSearch service = new LuceneSpecialCharactersSearch();
    String[] luceneSpecialCharacters = new String[]{"+", "-", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", "^", "\"", "~", "*", "?", ":", "\\"};

    // WHEN
    for (String specialCharacter : luceneSpecialCharacters) {
        String actual = service.search("list's special-characters " + specialCharacter);

        // THEN
        assertThat(actual, equalTo(LuceneSpecialCharactersSearch.TEXT_WITH_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS));
    }
}

private static class LuceneSpecialCharactersSearch {
    private static final String TEXT_WITH_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "This is the list's of special-characters + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ \" ~ ? : \\ *";

    private final IndexWriter writer;

    public LuceneSpecialCharactersSearch() throws Exception {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new TextField("body", TEXT_WITH_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS, Field.Store.YES));

        RAMDirectory directory = new RAMDirectory();
        writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new IndexWriterConfig(buildAnalyzer()));
        writer.addDocument(document);
        writer.commit();
    }

    public String search(String queryString) throws Exception {
        try (IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(writer, false)) {
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

            String escapedQueryString = QueryParser.escape(queryString).toLowerCase();

            Analyzer analyzer = buildAnalyzer();
            QueryParser bodyQueryParser = new QueryParser("body", analyzer);
            bodyQueryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);


            Query bodyQuery = bodyQueryParser.parse(escapedQueryString);
            BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
                    .add(new BooleanClause(bodyQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD))
                    .build();
            TopDocs searchResult = searcher.search(query, 1);

            return searcher.doc(searchResult.scoreDocs[0].doc).getField("body").stringValue();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds analyzer that is used for indexing and searching.
     */
    private static Analyzer buildAnalyzer() throws IOException {
        return CustomAnalyzer.builder()
                .withTokenizer("whitespace")
                .addTokenFilter("lowercase")
                .addTokenFilter("standard")
                .build();

    }
}
}
```