# C# - Lucene search is not working for few string literals

Tags: c#, .net, apache, lucene, lucene.net

We have implemented search for searching courses using Apache lucene. It's working fine. But, I have 2 records namely "Make it personnel" and "Do it right thing". When i search for "make" "personnel" i am getting results but when i search for "make it" no results are found. But it works well with "do it"! I am really confused as to why it's not working for "make it". BTW query parser is defined as below,

```
private readonly StandardAnalyzer _analyzer;
_analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, new[] { "Name",     "Description", "Id" }, _analyzer);

var queryParser = parseQuery(BuildPrefixQuery(input), parser);

var hits = searcher.Search(queryParser, null, 50, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
```

& and index creation code is

```
public void CreateIndex(List<ILucenceProperties> ListILucenceProperties)
    {
var writer = new IndexWriter(_directory, _analyzer, true,     IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

        foreach (var iLucenceProperties in ListILucenceProperties)
        {
            var document = new Document();

            document.Add(new Field("Id", iLucenceProperties.Id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("Name", iLucenceProperties.Name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("Description", iLucenceProperties.Description, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("Category", iLucenceProperties.Category, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
            document.Add(new Field("FilterID", iLucenceProperties.FilterID, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
            document.Add(new Field("ColumnName", iLucenceProperties.ColumnName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
            document.Add(new Field("AdditionalSearchParameter", iLucenceProperties.AdditionalSearchParameter, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
            writer.AddDocument(document);
        }

        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Dispose();
    }
```

Above, the "Name" field contains name of course, "Id" contains id of course, "Description" contains another id of course and so on.

It's my thought that the problem might be with parser/analyzer. Please help me out.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see a bit more code, specifically, the code that actually matches things with queries, and maybe even show us some real (if possible) sample data where these keywords are actually being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StandardAnalyzer` filters out the stop words, such as "it". But when you are searching you include the "it" as a keyword. You could use the [`StandardAnalyzer` constructor](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/df/d8b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_standard_1_1_standard_analyzer.html#ae751c5c15468793e9e335d4dc35eab9b) that takes a list of stop words, and call it with an empty set.

Comment: Super! Thank you. The following change worked. _analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29, CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);

Comment: But for courses such as "html/java programming" it's not working. i.e. When the special character "\" or "/" are part of the course name. We are allowing only these special characters to be part of the course names. Can you please help me out?

Comment: You could try to escape the special characters, or try another tokenizer. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107875/how-to-search-special-characters-in-lucene).

Comment: Yes, if we escape the special characters (previously we were replacing the special characters with empty string manually)  as Query query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuerystr)); (our parser is multi field parser. ) i can able to search "html/java programming" but i can't search for "html/java progr","html/java progra" etc, i.e it expects complete word now!