# Lucene is not returning the results if I am searching with special characters

Tags: java, lucene, special-characters

I am using Lucene 6.6.0 version, and I am indexing my data using StandardAnalyzer.

I am indexing following data of words.

1. a&e networks
2. a&e

After indexing , when I am searching with a&e it is not returning any results.
this is my sample code.

```
    Directory dir = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
    iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);

    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("text", "a&e networks", Field.Store.YES));
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("text", "a&e", Field.Store.YES));
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    writer.close();

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    Query query = new TermQuery(new Term("text", "a&e"));

    TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 5);
    final ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = results.scoreDocs;
    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : scoreDocs) {
        System.out.println(scoreDoc.doc + " " + scoreDoc.score + " " + searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc).get("text"));
    }
    System.out.println("Hits: " + results.totalHits);
    System.out.println("Max score:" + results.getMaxScore());
```

I am getting output as
**Hits: 0
Max score:NaN**

Even I am searching for **a** also it is not giving any results in this case.

but if I add stopwords set to StandardAnalyzer like this

```
    List<String> stopWords = Arrays.asList("&");
    CharArraySet stopSet = new CharArraySet(stopWords, false);
    IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer(stopSet));
```

and after that if i search for **a** then I am able to get the results. but even in that case also if i search for **a&e** , then I am not getting any results.

please suggest me how to achieve this, my goal here is if I search for **a&e** I should be able to get the results.  do I need to any CustomAnalyzer ? If so please explain what should I add in CustomAnalyzer?

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107875/how-to-search-special-characters-in-lucene

Answer (score 1):

Probably `&` character is considered as a word boundary:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html

> This class implements the Word Break rules from the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm, as specified in Unicode Standard Annex #29.

`a` and `e` are probably considered as stop word. So when indexed they are removed.

You can try some randomly generated keywords seperated by `&` character (eg. adsadaerewfds&eqeqwedasd). After indexing try to search keywords before and after `&`. If those keywords are found either store them without analyzing (you can use [StringField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html)) or create custom analyzer.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: In Lucene 6.0, the [StandardAnalyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) uses a stop-word list by default: "_... using a list of English stop words._". And `a` is one of those stop-words, which interferes with your query, @mahesh. Later versions of Lucene (I forget when the change happened) do not use a default list.

Comment: So,  for example, in [9.2.0](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html), the wording has changed: "_...using a configurable list of stop words_" which is empty by default. Your query, @mahesh, works as expected in Lucene 9.2.0 (for me).

Comment: yes @andrewJames , but when I am searching with a&e it is not giving any results. do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Because `a` is a stop-word @mahesh.

Comment: but if I add & in my stopwords list at that time If I search with **a**  able to get the results, but in this case if I search with a&e I am not getting results, why is that so?

Comment: When you give `&` as a stopword list you override stop word list. You can give an empty list as well. When the stopword list is overriden `a` is no longer in the stopword list, hence it comes as a result.